# How do I compress video from URI on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to capture video and send it to the server in base64. Before sending it, I want to check the video length  and video size. I am able to capture the video

```
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.camera_button:
                intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_VIDEO);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

and get the URI

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == INTENT_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
        }
    }
```

I am able to get a video path

```
    private String getPath(Uri video) {
        String path = video.getPath();
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(media, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }
```

How do I get a video object from that path so that I could compress, check video duration, file size?
For image, it will be as simple as this
`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);`

and after that, I would like to convert it to base64.
For image, it's as simple as this

```
    private String toBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, outputStream);
        byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Currently I am doing like this

```
    private String toBase64(Uri video) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            String path = getPath(video);
            File tmpFile = new File(path);
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tmpFile));
            long length = tmpFile.length();
            int inLength = (int) length;
            byte[] b = new byte[inLength];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(b)) != -1) {
                baos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

I get the base64, though I don't know if it's the correct one. but, I could not check video size, duration, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can compress video using [ffmpeg](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html). [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qAjo6wKhk9MVJjRjBKZTVkcFk/view?usp=sharing) is a sample project and [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qAjo6wKhk9TWpGQW93SXRDdFE/view?usp=sharing) is the library.